# image not show in listview from internal memory

Tags: android

i am using imageloader class as par this example :-http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

```
      >  String path = data.get(position).get("product_image");
       ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(activity);
        File directory = cw.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mypath=new File(directory,"Restaurant/"+path);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(mypath.toString(), producticon);
```

[image: this is path of where i store image in internal memory]

if use this code and its show image in listview but java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is getting.
please help me

```
      String path = data.get(position).get("product_image");
       ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(activity);

        //path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/dirName
        File directory = cw.getDir("files", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        File mypath=new File(directory,"Restaurant/"+path);

       Bitmap b;
        try {
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(mypath));
        //  b.compress(format, quality, stream)
             producticon.setImageBitmap(b);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` exception because of the size of the image. Let's resize it on the fly:

Instead of:
    `producticon.setImageBitmap(b);`

You should have:
    `producticon.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 120, 120, false));`

Where 120 will be the desired new height and width, respectively.

You'll found more information about handling Bitmaps on [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: hey now its working but if some more and high MB image are there then? its work?

Comment: Yes! The images remain there without being physically modified. They are just showed to the user in a smaller size but the original file remains untouched.

Comment: now its working, but if in past there are more image then?its work well?

Comment: Yes, why not? You could write a method that takes care of this line. You pass it a big Bitmap and it returns you a smaller Bitmap ready to put into your item of the ListView.

Comment: okay. if 200 smaller bitmap are then also not error come from memory?

Comment: hey can you explain little (b, 120, 120, false) this parameter of 120 120 its height and width??

Comment: Hey, I put 120 as an example of a small width and height. Put what you want! The parameters of `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` are the Bitmap source, the desired width, the desired height and a filter. You can find more data for [this method on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: Is this the best answer?